# Managing Package Manager Console commands for Entity Framework in project

Tags: c#, entity-framework, nuget

Entity Framework commands entered in the Package Manager Console, like `Add-Migration` and `Update-Database` can get fairly long and complex when when dealing with solutions that have a "non-standard" build.

With syntax and options like:

```
Add-Migration [-Name] <String> [-Force] [-ProjectName <String>] [-StartUpProjectName <String>] 
  [-ConfigurationTypeName <String>] [-ConnectionStringName <String>] [-IgnoreChanges] 
  [-AppDomainBaseDirectory <String>] [<CommonParameters>]

Add-Migration [-Name] <String> [-Force] [-ProjectName <String>] [-StartUpProjectName <String>] 
  [-ConfigurationTypeName <String>] -ConnectionString <String> -ConnectionProviderName <String> 
  [-IgnoreChanges] [-AppDomainBaseDirectory <String>] [<CommonParameters>]

Update-Database [-SourceMigration <String>] [-TargetMigration <String>] [-Script] [-Force] 
  [-ProjectName <String>] [-StartUpProjectName <String>] [-ConfigurationTypeName <String>] 
  [-ConnectionStringName <String>] [-AppDomainBaseDirectory <String>] [<CommonParameters>]

Update-Database [-SourceMigration <String>] [-TargetMigration <String>] [-Script] [-Force] 
  [-ProjectName <String>] [-StartUpProjectName <String>] [-ConfigurationTypeName <String>] 
  -ConnectionString <String> -ConnectionProviderName <String> 
  [-AppDomainBaseDirectory <String>] [<CommonParameters>]
```

Are there any good options to manage these commands within the project?  I often find myself creating a .txt file with notes and saved command lines, and saving it in a "doc" folder at the solution level.  I copy and paste commands from here as I need them, but it seems like there should be a better way to handle these commands.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to create a "batch file" (or something like it) for the Package Manager Console that can take simplified options and expand it to the full command.  For example, I run `Add-Migration-Ex MyNewMigration`, and it gets expanded to the full `Add-Migration` command, with all my other standard options and switches for the current project applied.

Are there any easier ways to manage these types of complex commands that makes them easier to save and run on a per-project / solution level?

Comment: How about using [`Set-Alias`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/set-alias?view=powershell-5.1)?

Comment: @DavidG Would that allow me to expand the command to include arguments that were not originally specified?  I don't see anything in the docs for it that looks like it would. Also, how would I run that command to create the alias to begin with?  Wouldn't I have to type in `Set-Alias ..blah blah` manually every time I open the solution?  Is there some equivalent to a "startup" script I can place in my solution that runs whenever it is opened?

Comment: Similar to using Set-Alias but can write some more indepth logic into your commands if you add commands to your NuGet_profile.ps1. This link has some examples that may give you some inspiration. http://pongit.be/productivity/package-manager-console-ef-migrations/

Comment: @NPhillips That looks like *almost* exactly what I'm looking for.  I see that the profiles are user specific, is there any way to have a solution specific profile?  Something that travels along with the solution and projects through source control, and would let me add solution specific commands, instead of commands that are global for the current user?  Even if not, this is far better than what I'm currently using.

Comment: @BradleyUffner That would be a nice idea, sadly I don't know of a way to do that. Seems like you should be able to add a .ps1 script into your solution and get nuget package manager to run Import-Module on load using a relative path. That may be worth a new question actually.

Comment: It looks like the profile script is run with the current directory set to the directory of the current solution, so I could have my profile search for something like "pmc.startup.ps1" and execute it if found.

Answer (score 1):

After doing a lot of research, I've found that NuGet has a system to run power-shell scripts at solution load.  Nuget will look for a script named "init.ps1" in the package's "tools" directory, and execute it whenever the solution loads.  I'm going to leverage this, and create a NuGet package that runs when the solution loads, that will check for a directory within the solution named "SolutionCommands".  It will then run any scripts, and install any modules located within that directory.  These scripts can be managed as part of the solution within Visual Studio, follow the solution around through version control, and automatically get distributed to all developers on the team.

I've created preliminary [package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AgentOctal.SolutionCommands) that is available on Nuget now for anyone else who would like this functionality.  It hasn't really been tested yet, and the scripts need to be signed (or the security policy of the computer relaxed) before they will run.

---

### init.ps1:

```
$oldLocation = Get-Location

$oldWarningPref = $WarningPreference
$WarningPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'

$commandDirectory = ".\SolutionCommands"

If(Test-Path $commandDirectory)
{
    Write-Host "Installing Modules..."
    Get-ChildItem $commandDirectory -Filter "*.psm1" |
    ForEach-Object {
        $fullPath = Join-Path -Path $commandDirectory -ChildPath $_.Name
        $fileName = Split-Path -Path $fullPath -Leaf
        $fileNameNoExtension = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($fullPath)

        if (Get-Module | ?{ $_.Name -eq $fileNameNoExtension })
        {
            Remove-Module $fileNameNoExtension
        }
        Import-Module ($fullPath)

        Write-Host "Loaded module: " $fullPath
        Write-Host "      Commands: " (Get-Command -Module $fileNameNoExtension)
        Write-Host
    }

    Write-Host "Executing Scripts..."
    Get-ChildItem $commandDirectory -Filter "*.ps1" |
    ForEach-Object {
        $fullPath = Join-Path -Path $commandDirectory -ChildPath $_.Name
        Write-Host $fullPath
        . $fullPath
    }
}

Set-Location $oldLocation
$WarningPref = $oldWarningPref
```